# Angularjs array of nested objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of **position** and nested **user** objects like so:

```
[ 
  position: {
    title: Developer,
    user: { name: Albert }
    },
  position: {
    title: CEO,
    user: { name: Smith }
    }
]
```

How do I get an array of [user, user] with Angularjs?

Comment: I think the solution you're after has nothing to do with angular, but with pure vanilla js,

Comment: I've tagged it with angular because that's the framework I'm using. A vanilla js solution would suit me fine.

Comment: @gion_13 It could have done. Angular has `angular.forEach` which polyfills Array.forEach. That could easily have been pertinent to the solution.

Comment: You should first fix the issue in your code snippet, because it is missing a few `{` and also `}`. from what I can see it doesn't seem to be an array, instead it  sounds like a single object. __But__ if it really is an array of positions it should be like: `[{title:'A', user:{}},{title:'B', user:{}}]` or at least: `[{position:{title:'A', user:{}}}, {position:{title:'B', user:{}}}]`

Comment: You're right @MehranHatami, I forgot to mention I was using coffeescript.

Comment: @RGraham: I wasn't arguing about the fact that it **can't** be done with angular. I was pointing out that the problem is out of the angular scope and suggesting that he should approach the issue using *plain old normal* javascript knowledge. Even if he uses angular, lodash or native functions, the logic itself stil has nothing to do with angular or it's purposes.  
It's just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is pseudo-code (as it's missing a few `{` and `}` and you'd need variables called Developer, Albert, CEO & Smith - I've fixed these in the *working example*) you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr = [{ 
  Position0: {
    title: Developer,
    user: { name: Albert }
    },
 {
  Position1 : {
    title: CEO,
    user: { name: Smith }
    }
}];
var result = arr.map(function(val, idx) {
    return val["Position" + idx].user.name;
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6dfjq0ov/)

Comment: Just a note for other newbies like me, | val["Position" + idx].user.name; | returns an array of values, | val["Position" + idx].user; | returns an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this code, and works ...

```
var positions, users;

users = [];
positions = [
  {
    title: 'Developer',
    user: { name: 'Albert' }
  },
  {
    title: 'CEO',
    user: { name: 'Smith' }
  }
];


angular.forEach(positions, function(position) {
  users.push(position.user);
});

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `angular.forEach()`:

```
var arr1=[]
var arr=[ 
  position: {
    title: Developer,
    user: { name: Albert }
    },
  position: {
    title: CEO,
    user: { name: Smith }
    }
];
angular.forEach(arr,function(value,key){
   arr1[key]=value.position.user;
});
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this thing does not need angularjs.

The way you can do that is  using for each loop:

```
var users = [];
var positions = [{ 
  Position0: {
    title: 'Developer',
    user: { name: 'Albert' }
    },

  Position1 : {
    title: 'CEO',
    user: { name: 'Smith' }
    }
}] 
    for(var i =0; i< positions.length; i++){
        for(var j in positions[i]){ //used to loop on object properties
          if(positions[i].hasOwnProperty(j)){ //checking if the property is not inherited
             if(positions[i][j].user){ //checking if the property exist, then only will push it to array, so that array doesnot have undefined values
                users.push(positions[i][j].user);
             }
          }
        }
    }
```

users array will have the users.